Stream camera stream using Gstreamer, WebRTC from device to react frontend on other device
I am new to Gstreamer and WebRTC. I have two arravisrc camera plugged into a Nvidia ORIN, I want to be able to stream both the camera feeds on demand to a react UI hosted on AWS. The ORIN might be behind NAT, so I read that we have to setup STUN/TURN server.
But for sake of simplicity, I want to start by streaming videotestsrc from the ORIN on demand. So  I was thinking of having a small server like Flask/FastAPI which can start the pipeline once a request is received. But I am not sure how to handle the webrtc part and how the pipeline or steps should look like.
Any guidance would help!

you can use webrtcsink which is a somewhat recent plugin which wraps the older webrtcbin which is a little difficult to handle. The code provides a sample web app and signalling server that can help you.
